# Is it possible to pass a value to the parameter of a function in PHP?

Tags: php

There is a `function` which returns a value :

```
function f($criteria, $extra_return)
{
   return $criteria['activity_code'];
}
```

I want to set a value to the $extra_return `parameter`. Is that possible in `PHP` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could use [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

```
function f($criteria, &$extra_return)
{
   $extra_return = 1;
   return $criteria['activity_code'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called [references](http://php.net/references). Here's an example from the manual where `$var` is shared between the caller and the function:

```
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a=5;
foo($a);
// $a is 6 here
```